# iOS8 Button setEnabled doesn't work

Tags: ios, uibutton, ios8

I just downloaded the iOS8 GM Seed, and found that my UIButtons, which are setEnabled when in app purchases are bought, are not working.

In

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
```

I have

```
[mainToneBtn setEnabled:YES];
```

Pre-iOS8 this updates the button to be clickable, but not now. I haven't done any changes pertaining to this, and in debug, the code above is hit. No code sets it back to setEnabled:NO.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you setting them enabled on the main thread?

Comment: @Acey Yes, this issue is specific to ios8.

Comment: In `viewDidLoad`, is `mainToneBtn` `nil`?

Comment: @vacawama nope, but your answer below works. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unable to reproduce your problem.  It seems, for whatever reason, that `ViewDidLoad` is now too early in the `ViewController` lifecycle for you to enable your buttons.  I would suggest trying to enable them later in `ViewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Comment: This works for me, thanks! But I still don't get it, why ios8 behaves differently from ios7 and before.

Comment: Actually putting the updateAllInAppPurchases in ViewDidLayoutSubviews turned out to be a problem for me, as I have other views in this viewController. Showing any of the other views causes ViewDidLayoutSubviews to load. I only want to activate updateAllInAppPurchases once on load.

Comment: Add a Boolean property or instance variable to your class called `inAppPurchasesUpdated`. Set it to `NO` in `ViewDidLoad`. Check to make sure it is `NO` in `ViewDidLayoutSubviews` before calling your update method, and then set it to `YES` in your update method.

Answer (score -1):

For some reason this works,

```
[self performSelector:@selector(updateAllInAppPurchases) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.001];
```

the button code is within updateAllInAppPurchases

but I have no idea why I have to do this in ios8. I will accept the answer of anyone who can give me a good explanation, thanks!